# Winlogon/RDP in Vista+: any way to replace the RDP session choose prompt?

Tags: authentication, windows-server-2008, rdp, winlogon

When someone logins to a RDP server (not Citrix, not a special terminal server, but a standart RDP access available in Windows Server), a **Windows logon** window gets displayed with a list of sessions.

[image: RDP access screenshot with RDP session list]

One astonishing thing is, this session prompt is displayed **AFTER** authorization, and there can be up to three sessions, and they still can't be distinguished in other means rather by looking at 'logged on' time.

*Nevermind the console tools [do exist](https://serverfault.com/a/153509) to attach the proper session, to examine the session content etc; and we've already adopted them; there's also a possibility to lots of things around fixed session IDs (e.g. first session for admin console, second session for application tests).* - I want to replace that session list with something more custom.

In older Windows editions, it was possible to write GINA module to tamper with authorization; not sure if it was possible to override the mentioned functionality; nowadays it seems that current API is even more [restricted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756900.aspx).

**Question:**
Can you provide any recommendations/examples on authoring complete replacement for this part of logon pocess?

Comment: Which programming language are you using to solve this problem?

Comment: @CodyGray, I am not interested in getting active session list in any programming language - but want to know is it possible to replace that prompt with something else (as it was possible with GINA).

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that. Someone could probably answer that question, and it would probably be on-topic for a programming Q&A site.

Comment: @CodyGray, done with updating, what do you think now?